# AttributeError: module 'pika' has no attribute 'BlockingConnection' error in rabbitmq

Tags: python, python-3.x, rabbitmq, queue, pika

Recently I tried using pika library to make a queue as the documentation of rabitmq ([rabbitmq_tutorials_partOne](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html)) I typed this code:

```
import pika

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')

channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                  routing_key='hello',
                  body='Hello World!')
print(" [x] Sent 'Hello World!'")

connection.close()
```

However I've got this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'pika' has no attribute 'BlockingConnection'
```

My installed pika version is : **0.12.0**.
and I used this command to install pika : `pip3 install pika`.
I couldn't realize what is my problem.
Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: What is the output of `python --version` and `pip3 list`?

Comment: Python 3.6.5 and use this link to see all pip installed packages:
[pip3 list](https://textuploader.com/dec5k)

Comment: it fixed automatically, I don't know why this happen, and I don't know why it fixed by it self.

Comment: this would happen if your test file was named "pika.py".

Answer (score 0):

1- you have not installed the Pika library
2- you should name your file something other than pika.py.

i hope its helping you